# How to recover the text in url and convert text back?

Tags: python

How to display the text in the url: `https://www.example.com?city=%u5B81%u6CE2&district=%u911E%u5DDE`

The encoding of the page `GB18030`.

I tried to use `html.unescape` and `urllib.parse.unquote` but I cannot get the desired simplified Chinese characters.

What should I do?

If I have the text `常州` and `天宁` and want to convert it to the code `%abcd%wxyz`, what can I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the solution:

Question 1:

"https://www.example.com?city=%u5B81%u6CE2&district=%u911E%u5DDE".replace("%", "\\").encode("utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")

Question 2:

'常州天宁'.encode("unicode_escape").decode("utf-8").replace('\\', '%')

Comment: It works. Thanks, Chan.